# How to use webpack2 to load ttf file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

I am using webpack2 but failed to load ttf file. I defined my scss file as below:

`fonts/font-roboto.scss`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto-Bold;
  src: url('./roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf');
}
```

when I import this file from `src/components/App.jsx` as below

```
import '../fonts/font-roboto.scss';
```

I get below error:

```
ERROR in ../~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!../~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":true}!../~/resolve-url-load
er!../fonts/font-roboto.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url-loader' in '/Users/joey/dev/reactjs/jump/src'
 @ ../~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!../~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":true}!../~/resolve-url-loader!../
fonts/font-roboto.scss 6:84-126
 @ ../fonts/font-roboto.scss
 @ ./components/App.jsx
 @ ./index.jsx
 @ multi babel-polyfill ./index.jsx
```

I am not sure how to solve this problem. My webpack configure file is as:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './index.jsx'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'app.[hash].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.(jsx?)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|.tmp-globalize-webpack)/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=assets/[hash].[ext]',
          'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg)$/i,
        use: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'react-svg-loader',
            query: {
              svgo: {
                plugins: [{
                  removeTitle: false
                }],
                floatPrecision: 2
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|eot|ttf|woff2)(\?.*$|$)/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=images/[hash].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ hash: false, template: './index.html' })
  ],
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    module: 'empty'
  }
};
```

my folder structure is shown as below:

[image]

After install `url-loader` the error is gone but I got below warning message on browser console:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: data:application/font-woff;base64,bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBfX3dlYnBhY2tfcHVib…BhdGhfXyArICJpbWFnZXMvZDMyOWNjOGIzNDY2N2YxMTRhOTU0MjJhYWFkMWIwNjMudHRmIjs=
localhost/:1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the error message you posted:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url-loader'`

It appears you need to install `url-loader` - do this with `npm i url-loader --save` in your terminal.

Comment: You are right, after install `url-loader` the error is resolved. But I got a warning message and I have posted. Could you help to look at it?

Answer (score 1):

Change this bit of your configuration from:

```
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|eot|ttf|woff2)(\?.*$|$)/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=100000&mimetype=application/font-woff",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=images/[hash].[ext]",
      }
```

to:

```
  {
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: "file-loader?name=images/[hash].[ext]",
  }
```